# how to mock slack web api for jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking, slack

i have an app that's using the `@slack/web-api` package through the named import `WebClient`.

i want to test one of the controllers that uses a model that in turns uses the slack web api.

something like this:

```
// model.ts
import { WebClient } from '@slack/web-api';

export default (token) => {
  const slackWebClient = new WebClient(token);
  return {
    func: () => slackWebClient.chat.postMessage(...)
  }
}

// controller.ts
import model from './model'

export const controller = async () => {
  const m = model(token)
  await model.func()
}
```

as for my testing, i tried to mock the package then test the behaviour of the `chat.postMessage` function but i keep getting 0 calls despite when adding a console.log right next to it i get an output.

this is my test:

```
import { controller } from '../controller';

const mSlack = {
  chat: {
    postMessage: jest.fn(),
  },
};

jest.mock('@slack/web-api', () => {
  return { WebClient: () => mSlack };
});

it('test controller', async () => {
  await controller()

  expect(mSlack.chat.postMessage).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
})
```

this is a simplified version of my code as my code would be very large and i already tested all other aspects and i'm getting the desired responses. my problem is not with the testing itself but with the mock since the tested code is reachable but i'm missing something on how to assert on it.

i'm also using typescript with nodejs for this app.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are testing `controller.ts` but `@slack/web-api` is imported from `model.ts`. even though controller imports model however jest does not mock it. You can only mock libraries which are directly imported in `controller.ts` (in this case).

My suggestion is to mock `model.ts` itself rather than its dependencies.

Comment: i don't think that's the case because i have other models that i'm mocking their dependencies and i'm getting the desired results. only with the slack api that i'm facing this problem.

Comment: Can you give example of those cases?

Comment: Have you tried to set mocked value to null to see if it throws error?

Comment: jest.mock('@slack/web-api', () => {
  return { WebClient: () => null};
});

Comment: the issue i had was with the way i reset the mocks, thanks for the help, truly appreciated